# Why this discord.js mongoose query didnt work?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

Hello guys i want to take data from database then show as bot reply.
but i got error

This is the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const profileSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userID: String,
    nickname: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", profileSchema);
```

this is how i call the data

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "!n"){
      // reply by User find by _id mongoose
      const data = User.findOne({ userID: msg.author.id })
      const nick = data.nickname;
      if (!data) return msg.reply({content: 'You have no data'})
      msg.reply({content: `Your nickname is ${nick}`})
  }
});
```

And the discord bot reply

> "Your nickname is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How users are saving there nicknames?
what is command ?
also try `console.log(data.nickname)` or `console.log(nick)`

Comment: I try command both console.log and it show undefined both.

Comment: Did you define Schema on top of the event?